# Regex with $ anchor and look ahead

Tags: javascript, regex, perl

`/ab(?=.{1})$/g` doesn't match "abdabd" or anything else

It's the anchor $ that is troubling me. What can this regex match ?

Comment: This regex cannot match anything. It's trying to look ahead into the `$` anchor.

Comment: The `(?=.{1})` expects to find a character at the end, but you won't let it because you put the EOS at that spot. Teach a man to fish ..

Comment: oh ok, it's like asking to find two different things at the same time. Like "ab" followed by a single character and "ab" followed by EOS ?

Comment: @airmet did you want explanation or solution.

Comment: @airnet Yes, and the order doesn't matter: `/ab$(?=.)/` means the same thing.

Comment: @Borodin did you notice that op also want to modify his regex to find a match?

Comment: Another way to explain this: lookarounds don’t consume characters. `(?=.{1})$` doesn’t mean “match one character and then match the EOS”, it means “expect one character, but definitely match the end of string”, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can this regex match ?

This regex won't match anything and is guaranteed to fail because:

```
ab       - will literally match ab
(?=.{1}) - will use lookup to make sure there is at least 1 character after ab
$        - will assert end of input after ab
```

both conditions can never be met hence your regex will always fail.

Comment: Note that `/ab(?=.{1})$/sg` would match `"ab\n"`

Comment: @ikegami: There is no `s` (DOTALL) in JS

Comment: My comment applies to Perl. I didn't know the question was also tagged JS.