# Puzzled by use of .{1} in regex

Tags: regex

In a couple recent questions here on Stack Overflow, I've seen the regex sequence `.{1}`.  In the regex engines with which I'm familiar, a repeat count of 1 is strictly redundant.

Is there a regex engine that I am unaware of for which this is not true?

Could this explicit count of 1 be an attempt to comment/highlight that the preceding `.` is a metacharacter?

I'm just trying to understand the motivations for this practice.

---

Links: [Regex with $ anchor and look ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683167/regex-with-anchor-and-look-ahead) is the most recent...  looking for the other...

Comment: It can very well be single dot. I'm not aware of any regex engine where `.{1}` is different from `.`

Comment: @Jongware That is a plausible explanation...

Comment: @Jongware: I imagine you meant "You can put `{1}` _after_ anything", rather than _before_.  Do you want to delete and re-create your comment so it can be upvoted?

Comment: Can you link those 'recent questions', so we can look at the occurrences in-context?

Comment: It would be better to link to questions where this is used in the **answer**, not the question. People who write questions often don't know what they're doing, so you shouldn't take their code as examples of good coding.

Comment: I'm not sure I've seen it in an answer, but the fact that I'd seen it repeated in questions made me think there's a sub-culture with which I am unfamiliar.

Comment: You can put `{1}` after anything, metacharacter or not. "In a couple recent questions here" suggests Magical thinking and/or Cargo cult programming. A bit like adding backslashes before just about anything. (Magical Thinking = "it worked elsewhere so it must also work here"; Cargo Cult Programming = "I copied this fragment from a working example".)

Comment: Related: [Does the quantifier {0} make sense in some scenarios?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7511600/7586)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting `{1}` after any repeatable term has no effect whatsoever.

I could understand if `{1}` appeared in a regex that was *generated* using a variable for the count of a term, eg:

```
String regex = "foo.{" + n + "}bar";
```

to match `"foo"` and `"bar"` separated by `n` characters. When `n` happened to be `1`, you would get `"foo.{1}bar"`.

Comment: I can tell you that I have done exactly this sort of thing in the past, where I had to write code to take some sort of proprietary format string and convert it into regex.  I would end up with a counter for the number of consecutive occurrences, and that would get converted to `"{" + count + "}"`.  When `count == 1`, it was easier to just leave it in, since the regex engines parsed it correctly and it required no modification to my code.

Comment: Fair answer (+1), but I'm not sure it matches the context in which I'd seen it.

Comment: That's really the only context where it makes any sense that you would have something like that.  Otherwise, it's just cruft.

Comment: The same argument can be said for `{0}`. It and the token before is redundant, but the construct allows for generated regex to work without having to deal with conditions and stuffs.